# Unable to see organizations when login from a different computer

Tags: github

Hello I am loging into my work github on a different repository, however none of my work machine's repos (and organizations) show up in spite of it being the same login. Are there any permissions that must be granted for remote access?

Answer (score 0):

There is no "remote access" when it comes to github.com: only a GitHub account and its password, than can be entered from any post.

The same principle should apply for a GitHub for Enterprise instance (possible linked to an enterprise LDAP user referential), provided you are using the same user/password account as usual, even if your remote session is done under a different account.

> I just go to github.com and log with my work credentials

That is not how github.com credentials work: your "work" credentials have nothing to do with your GitHub account. Use the login/password of your GitHub account, *not* your "work" credentials.

Comment: So why can't I see the organizations I can see in my work computer?

Comment: @HGB Are you using GitHub for Enterprise? And are you using the same *GitHub* account (no matter what your OS login is)?

Comment: I am literally using my work github login from home and none of the organizations I can see at work are visible

Comment: @HGB Is the GitHub you are accessing a GitHub for enterprise?

Comment: It must be as it is used at work. I do not have admin rights. All I know is that when I log in at work I see a list of organizations and repo and nothing at home.

Comment: @HGB So you confirm this is an on premise private repo hosting server right? Not github.com?

Comment: @HGB So your organizations are on github.com?

Comment: @HGB I have edited my answer to confirm you must then use your GitHub account credentials, not your "work" credentials.

Comment: I really don't know how to explain myself better. When at work I log with my Work credentials, under my user I see 2 organizations of which I am part. When at home, I log in with the SAME credentials and my account is EMPTY, no organizations, no repo. Nothing. But it is the SAME ACCOUNT on GITHUB. Just a different laptop.

Comment: @HGB Well, one explanation is that, at work, you might not access the same GitHub instance, meaning that at work, you might be using a private GitHub for Enterprise instance, but since it looks so much like github.com, you might have mixed up the two. Is that possible?